# MongoDB document's @Id to be a property of an HashMap?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a class which it's only field is an HashMap.

Is it possible to define the @Id of the class to be one of the keys of the HashMap? (which always exists there)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Class that contains only an HashMap don't define a Class because it not make any sense, instead convert your query result directly in an Map likes `Map<String, Object> dbCursor = mongoTemplate.getCollection("articles").find(query.getQueryObject(), Map.class).first();`

I suggest you to use the Class in order to define your object, maybe you can use something like

```
public class Foo {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Map<String, Object> data;

    private Map<String, Object> metadata;
}
```

in order to maintain flexibility